# Cocoa-Touch: How to find out if CGPoint is in a certain CGRect?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitouch, cgpoint

I was wondering if there is a simple way to find out if a certain point is in a certain CGRect?

I have this to get the position of where the user touched the screen:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];    
CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView:self.view];
```

No I would like to find out if this point is in the following rect:

```
CGRect aFrame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 200);
```

The following does obviously not work:

```
if (currentPosition = aFrame) {//do something}
```

I'd be grateful for any help. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `CGRectContainsPoint` function to determine if point lies inside a rectangle:

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(aFrame, currentPosition))
   // Do something
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need is [CGGeomery reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html) especially the [`CGRectContainsPoint`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectContainsPoint) function.